# Can't connect to subnet via OpenVPN with forwarding with iptables

Tags: iptables, openvpn, nat, subnet, ubuntu-18.04

I have a small switched subnet with a few devices that communicate with IP. They are connected via ethernet to an ODroid running Ubuntu 18.04 that is also in an OpenVPN. (The ODroid is connected to the internet atm with WiFi, will be changed to LTE later)
I want to address a service running on the devices in that subnet from a computer that is also in the VPN.

```
+-----------------+          +------------------+      +--------------------+
|A Device         | ethernet |ODroid            |  VPN |Controlling Computer|
|eth0: 192.168.2.2+----------+tun0: 10.8.0.5    +------+tun0: 10.8.0.2      |
+-----------------+          |eth0: 192.168.2.1 |      +--------------------+
                             +------------------+
```

I tried to use iptables with nat to make the controlling computer able to access the device behind the ODroid.

```
[on the ODroid]
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I also enabled forwarding on the ODroid

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

I also added static routes to all devices:

```
[on the ODroid] ip r
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.5 
85.214.205.172 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.106 metric 600 
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1
```

```
[on the controlling computer] ip r
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp33s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.2 
[ip of my server] via 192.168.0.1 dev enp33s0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp33s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp33s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.105 metric 100 
192.168.2.0/24 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0
```

```
[on the device I want to connect to] ip r
default via 192.168.2.1 dev enp0s25 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.8.0.0/24 via 192.168.2.1 dev enp0s25 
192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.2.1 dev enp0s25 
192.168.2.0/24 dev enp0s25 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.109 metric 100 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

I can ping the ODroid from both the controlling computer and from the device I want to connect to.

From the device that has the service I want to connect to, I can connect to the controlling computer, so NAT in that direction seems to work.
But I can't connect the other way around.

I have tried just using one of

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

but that didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A copule of assorted things. 1) I failed to completely parse the requirements as you seem to use the term computer to refer to different things. 2) Masquerading on `tunX` is never needed: you only need to masquerade on an interface which does NAT, and that is only needed in very specific settings (like having only a single "white" IP on the Internet). 3) Netfilter rules also contain default (policies) for each chain; if you explicitly enable certain traffic in the FORWARD chain, that hints you have non-default policies for the other chains, too. This might explain certain packets get dropped.

Comment: 4) The usual approach to debugging such stuff is to run `tcpdump` on specific interfaces of all the involved machines in turn. Things to check: a) whether there exists traffic on tun0 (looks like yes, it does); b) whether traffic exists _outside_ of the tun0: say, on ODroid box that would be on eth0.